# In jenkins pipeline getting issue Docker daemon socket at unix when doing docker build in Kubernetes pod of azure kubernetes services

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

m getting the docker daemon issue ,dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
Update docker file

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
LABEL maintainer ashish<ashish@gmail.com>

USER root
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install sudo && \
    yes |apt-get install vim
# system preparation    
RUN sudo apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common curl
RUN sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https

 # Install Docker client
ENV DOCKER_BUCKET download.docker.com
ENV DOCKER_VERSION 19.03.8
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install docker-ce
RUN docker -v

RUN sudo /etc/init.d/docker start
# RUN sudo systemctl enable docker
#  kubectl
COPY kubectl ./kubectl
RUN curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
RUN chmod +x kubectl \
 && mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/bin/docker"
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
 
 #Switch user to jenkins
# USER jenkins
```

inside the container i cann see docker -v
but docker ps is not working.
is there any docker client also i need to download,which will run my docker-daemon

Comment: Hello @ashishSober. Have you tried to add user `jenkins` to group `docker`? Run: `sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins` and than restart Jenkins.

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor, From where this command shall i run,as i found this solution in many places

Comment: Hello @ashishSober. In your shell.

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor,but this issue is coming at host ,jenkins pipeline ,when i try to create the image ```dockerImage = docker.build registry + ":$BUILD_NUMBER"```

Comment: Please check out [this doc](https://techoverflow.net/2017/03/01/solving-docker-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket/) and try the solution I have proposed in my previous comments. If that would still not work for you, we will dig deeper.

Comment: I ran,getting this  
``` sudo: usermod: command not found 
```

Comment: Check if `usermod` is located in `/sbin` and try to adjust the command to `sudo /sbin/usermod -a -G docker jenkins`.

Comment: same not found, can we do at deployment.yaml file,so the change will repflect at the time of apply

Comment: Have you actually checked the location of `usermod` before running the command again?  For example, when running Debian, the full path would be `/usr/sbin/usermod`.

Comment: m using mac machine,there i dont know how to check

Comment: try checking if the file exists  and permissions are right by running ls -la. if its says no such file or... try a diferent location, if it exists but you dont have execute permissions that could be the problem

Comment: @NoamYizraeli it gives me the list of file,but i didn't got anything related to the usermod

Comment: If the file exists (as I understand from you) It should give you the permissions set on the file in a Linux `ls -l` command form with rxw for user, group and else and - when no permission for specific permission, it doesn't do that?

Comment: now i can able to find the usermod but the docker not found error is coming,how to install the docker in jenkins container

Comment: you set hostPath to the worker node docker socket which is right, BUT the pod securityContext does not grant root access to the volume AND the container securityContext does not allow privilege escalation, so how can work, it cannot. 
When you make it work locally, you set --priviledge, so it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a custom docker image in your deployment which will consist both Jenkins and Docker therefore should resolve your problem. You will need to have docker in your Mac First.

1. Write Docker File with name `Dockerfile`

```
FROM  jenkins/jenkins:lts

RUN yum install docker -y

EXPOSE 8080
```

2. Build an Image

```
docker build -t <name of your image> .
```

This will build your image on your machine with both Jenkins and Docker inside it. You can verify the image using the following command:

```
docker images
```

3. Use the following image in your Deployment

Replace your image in `Deployment` with your custom image.

For more understanding of this use case then check this [link](https://gist.github.com/afloesch/ea855b30cfb9f157dda8c207d40f05c0) out.

Comment: Try adding `systemctl enable docker`

Comment: Now i ran  ```  sudo systemctl enable docker ``` getting output Synchronizing state of docker.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable docker
but stll facing the same issue.

Comment: Try not to mount docker.sock as a volume in your deployment now because you have already installed it.

Comment: still the same error ```  Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? ```

Comment: update the docker file,you can see in the question asked

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue comes from the fact that when it works on your local dev machine, you had used `--priviledged`.

In you deployment manifest you set hostPath to the worker node docker socket which is right, BUT neither the pod securityContext does not grant any elevated access to the mountPath, nor the container securityContext not allowing privilege escalation.

There is no way this can work unless you allow more elevated priviledges either at the pod level or at the container level security contexts.

Comment: no i have created a custom image which installs  docker inside the jenkins container and with the help of sudo I changed the permission, but now getting error 
       ``` Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?   
```